# Can a 3.2V, 400mAh battery charge a smartphone?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, cellphone

I have a solar panel that slowly charges this battery and I am thinking of trying to make a cell phone charger out of it. I know it won't be fast, but will it be able to charge a phone?
[image: The battery in question]

Comment: Yes (with a 5V DCDC step up converter), but the amount of enery in that cell is at most an hour of smartphone usage. Usable power banks have about 10 times the charge in mAh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but most smart phones want 5V to charge, so you'll need to boost the voltage.

DC boost convertes are available online at good prices.

do a search on "USB 5V boost" prices start at less than a dollar.

14430 cell pictured does not have match the energy capacity of most cellphones, so you may need several of those cells to do a full charge.
Many powerbanks are based on the larger 18650 cell.

Comment: 3.2 V x 400 mAh = 1280 mWh or 1.2 Wh. The Samsung Galaxy S4, for example is rated at 3.8 V x 2800 mAh = 10.6 Wh. This is eight times the capacity of the cell in the photo. It hasn't a hope of charging the S4 or most smartphones even if the 5 V conversion was 100% efficient. It might suffice as a 10% reserve tank.

Comment: it can provide a partial charge, but yeah not a full charge.  I'll add that.

Comment: It will be hooked up to a solar panel, so it should be able to give a my phone a decent charge, albeit a slow one

Comment: yeah, that'll work.

Comment: I already purchased one, but do you have any recommendations for websites to buy electronic parts and pieces?

Comment: maker sites like "pimoroni" "sparkfun" "adafruit" and "futurlec" are a good source for modules,  but they usually be had at better prices from one of the on-line marketplaces like "ebay", "alieexpress", or "banggood" if you know what you are looking for.

Comment: That green tick you gave is sufficient, Comments are not for 'thank you' etc.